# Validate last modified date to expire the password for the user

Tags: java, date, calendar, simpledateformat

I need to check password expired or not. If he is not modified the password for last 30 days i need to ask him to reset the password. Here is my code.

```
   Date lastPasswordModifiedDate =new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("10/30/2013");
    if (lastPasswordModifiedDate == null)
    {           
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTimeInMillis(0);
        lastPasswordModifiedDate = cal.getTime();
    }

    Calendar lastPasswordChangeCal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();
    lastPasswordChangeCal.setTime(lastPasswordModifiedDate);
    Date today = new Date();
    lastPasswordChangeCal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,  -30); //max 30 dates to expire
    Date expireDate = lastPasswordChangeCal.getTime();
    System.out.println(expireDate);  //last password changed date
    System.out.println(today);  //today date - I changed in my system
    System.out.println(today.after(expireDate));
```

when i print this

```
    System.out.println(expireDate);
    System.out.println(today);
    System.out.println(today.after(expireDate));
    Mon Sep 30 00:00:00 IST 2013
    Tue Oct 30 22:07:44 IST 2012
    false
```

I am expecting if lastPasswordModifiedDate >30 days or null it should returns true.

Comment: You've been around long enough to know that it's impossible to help if you don't actually say what's wrong.

Comment: What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified code:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
Date today = cal.getTime();

if(lastPasswordModifiedDate == null)
// put today in database as lastModifiedDate and return

Date lastPasswordModifiedDate =new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").parse("10/30/2013");
lastPasswordModifiedDate.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,  30); //max 30 dates to expire
if(today.after(lastPasswordModifiedDate))
// password expired
else
// password valid
```

Comment: if lastPasswordModifiedDate  is null then?

Comment: You should take the user/password creation date in that case, you can handle that on the database side when you fetch the date values.

Comment: its is null in the Database.

Comment: When you add a new user tuple in your table, do you put null values for lastPasswordModifiedDate ? If yes then you should actually put current date when inserting. Putting null doesnt make sense does it ? You know the lastPasswordModified date, so why not use it...

Comment: Aakash Yes i accept it but i cant change for existing users. Some users not updating the password at first time when they login like they are guest users. any idea for null date?

Comment: Check my edit, I think since you dont know the user creation date this is the only option. If you know the user creation date then as I mentioned you should take that as the lastModifiedDate

Answer (score 1):

As you have changed your system time to `Tue Oct 30 22:07:44 IST 2012`, so these statements

```
System.out.println(expireDate);  //last password changed date
System.out.println(today);  //today date - I changed in my system
System.out.println(today.after(expireDate));
```

printing these outputs

```
Mon Sep 30 00:00:00 IST 2013
Tue Oct 30 22:07:44 IST 2012
false
```

as your `today` is not `after` expireDate. And if you don't change your system date to `2012`, the last statement will print `true`. So, I think you are doing it correctly, you just need to check:

```
if(today.after(expireDate)){
// Change Password
} else {
// proceed
}
```

Comment: Thanks Debojit Saikia i got the answer from Aakash Goyal answer. for testing purpos only i changed the date